# Difference between HDF5 file and PyTables file

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, pytables

Is there a difference between `HDF5` files and files created by `PyTables`?

`PyTables` has two functions `.isHDFfile()` and `.isPyTablesFile()` suggesting that there
is a difference between the two formats.

I've done some looking around on Google and have gathered that PyTables is built on top of HDF, but I wasn't able to find much beyond that.

I am specifically interested in interoperability, speed and overhead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PyTables files are HDF5 files.

However, as I understand it, PyTables adds some extra metadata to the attributes of each entry in the HDF file.

If you're looking for a more "vanilla" hdf5 solution for python/numpy, have a look a `h5py`.

It's less database-like (i.e. less "table-like") than PyTables, and doesn't have as many nifty querying features, but it's much more straight-forward, in my opinion.  If you're going to be accessing an hdf5 file from multiple different languages, `h5py` is probably a better route to take.